# How to create a NUMA topology in single system environment

Tags: linux, numa

I want to know if it possible to create a NUMA topology(2 NUMA nodes is also fine) in a single system environment (I'm using virtualbox ubuntu 18.04).

When I run `$numactl -H`, I see the following

```
available: 1 nodes (0)
node 0 cpus: 0 1 2 3
node 0 size: 1992 MB
node 0 free: 477 MB
node distances:
node   0 
  0:  10
```

I was wondering if it is really possible to create two NUMA nodes (just for simulating distributed environment) in a system having 4 cores. Or do I need to have more than four cores for doing so?

Comment: To clarify: You're trying to create a test NUMA topology on a single host?

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to create a test NUMA topology on a single host.

Answer (score -1):

In virtualization the number of total cores you can assign to all VMs is near infinite. But the number of cores you can assign to each individual VM cannot exceed the total number of logical cores on the host.

**So, to put it concisely: Yes, you can create as many NUMA cores as your host can handle.**

Hypervisors use a scheduler to queue each VM's CPU instructions to the host's CPU. The more VMs you set up just means there's a longer queue heading through the hypervisor's scheduler into the host's CPU, which means things slow down, but they don't fail. CPUs and modern system architectures are designed to handle queues, and this is actually one reason why virtualization is such a useful and powerful thing: It keeps the queue on the host more full more of the time, more efficiently using the hosts's resources.

Comment: How to create NUMA cores?

Comment: That is not what your question is about. If you have a different question now that this one is answered, first, mark this as the correct answer using the checkmark icon to the left of this answer, and second, ask a new question. However "How to create NUMA cores" is a process likely already well documented for your preferred hypervisor, and so you should do some further research before asking it to make sure you haven't missed an already existing guide answering your question.